# Rails 4: How to make a PATCH request from controller?

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, request

How I could make a **PATCH** request from controller? I need do that for use an external API.

Answer (score 0):

I an not sure what you are trying to do but this should work

```
 redirect_to url_for(:controller => :controller_name, :action => :action_name, :method => 'Patch')
```